# Error con matplotlib al ejecutarlo desde insomnia

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Estoy creando gráficas con panda y matplot y al ejecutarlo manualmente desde el backend me va estupendo, pero si ahora intento pasarlo para consumirlo en API me salta este error, como se puedo solucionar eso si es que es posible¿?

Dice que solo trabaja en el hilo principal....

ValueError: signal only works in main thread